# WPF: ComboBox DisplayMemberPath is suddenly not shown anymore?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, combobox, namespaces

in my ComboBox I see 3 times this: MyNameSpace.ViewModel.CustomerViewModel ??

Actually this code worked but now don`t know what I changed:

```
      <ComboBox  DisplayMemberPath="{Binding Path=CustomerName}" SelectedIndex="0" ItemsSource="{Binding CustomersViewModel}" />
```

Customers is a ObservableCollection

The same code works fine with a ListBox just using DisplayMemberBinding instead of DisplayMemberPath.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DisplayMemberPath takes a path, not a Binding. So just set DisplayMemberPath="CustomerName".